# Restructure object array with key value pairs in Javascript and output or emit it to save it with mongoose and MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, mongoose

I am new to JS and use node.js, express, and mongoose and have an incoming array with random and unpredictable key-value pairs.

```
 // Example
 const simpleArray = {
      d: "h",
      e: "i",
      f: "j",
      g: "k",
    };
```

I need to restructure this array in order to push it in my Mongo-database. So the result of the above restructured example needs to look like this:

```
// Restructured example
user.details.d.push({name:"h", date: Date.now(),});
user.details.e.push({name:"i", date: Date.now(),});
user.details.f.push({name:"j", date: Date.now(),});
user.details.g.push({name:"k", date: Date.now(),});

// After this restructering, I like to push it to the user database:
const user = await User.findById(userId);
await user.save();
```

I've spent hours to restructure the simpleArray and am ending up with one options:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(basis)) {
      console.log(
        `user.details.${key}.push({name:"${value}", date: Date.now(),});`
      );
    }
```

Problem: I don't like to log it to the console. I must provide it before 'await user.save();'. If I replace console.log() with return, suddenly it does not work anymore. What to do that it is made available for 'await user.save();' and store it in the database??
I googled a lot and there to often console.log() is used instead of practical ways of further using the code.

In the end it should work like this:

```
// Example
     const simpleArray = {
          d: "h",
          e: "i",
          f: "j",
          g: "k",
        };

//Loop
     for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(basis)) {
          console.log(
            `user.details.${key}.push({name:"${value}", date: 
     Date.now(),});`
            );
          }
//Result
//user.details.d.push({name:"h", date: Date.now(),});
//user.details.e.push({name:"i", date: Date.now(),});
//user.details.f.push({name:"j", date: Date.now(),});
//user.details.g.push({name:"k", date: Date.now(),});



// Push to database
     const user = await User.findById(userId);
     await user.save();
```

Comment: Why do you log it though? Can't you just use the code from the example? Something like: `user.details[key].push({name: value, date: Date.now()})`?

Comment: This does not work:

var user = await User.findById(userId);

 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(basis)) {
      `user.details.${key}.push({name:"${value}", date: Date.now(),});`;
    } 

await user.save();

If I hardcode an restructured example before await user.save, it works fine. But not with this function. So the data model works and suits.

Comment: The syntax for accessing a key is not `object.${key}`, but rather `object[key]`. Also, if you want to interpolate strings, `"${value}"` will not work, ` `${value}` ` is the correct syntax (backquotes instead of double quotes). If `value` is already a string though, you can use `value` directly instead of enclosing it in a string.

Comment: But if I console.log it, it is providing the needed and above stated // Restructured example. So I think it obviously works.

Comment: The result of the loop function should return and look like the "Restructured example". The Restructured example is the result of the loop based on the simpleArray in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the working solution:

```
 // Loop over random array
    Object.keys(simpleArray).forEach((item) => {
            user.details[item].push({
            name: simpleArray[item],
            date: Date.now(),
          });
        });
```